# How to set dynamic data in angular routing module

Tags: angular

I'm facing the following situation with my angular application.

I have designed an angular application that uses run-time configuration so that the configuration from a `config.json` file is read before the bootstrapping of the application using the `APP_INITIALIZER` provider in `AppModule`. The data from the configuration file is provided as an `AppConfiguration` object through an `AppConfigService` service. This is working as expected.

The problem comes because I want a `role` property of the route `data` in `AppRoutingModule` to be configurable and this value must be provided by the `AppConfigService` that contains my configuration.

This is how I'm dealing with this scenario:

In the `AppModule` class, I`m initializing the application this way:

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...  
  ],
  imports: [
  ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
  ...
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService, KeycloakService],
    },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the initializer function, I'm calling to the `AppConfigService::loadConfig` method that reads the data from the `config.json` file and populates an `AppConfiguration` object.

**app-init.ts**

```js
export function initializer(configService: AppConfigService, keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<boolean> {
  return () => {
    // Load configuration from config.json file
    return configService.loadConfig()
      .then((): Promise<boolean> => {
        // Initialize keycloak
        ...
      });
  };
}
```

**app-config.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {

  private _configuration: AppConfiguration;

  public get configuration() {
    return this._configuration;
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public async loadConfig() {
    try {
      const data: AppConfiguration = await this.httpClient
          .get<AppConfiguration>(AppSettings.CONFIG_JSON_FILE)
          .toPromise();
      this._configuration = data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.error);
    }
  }
}
```

In my `AppRoutingModule`, I'm trying to set the `role` value in the `routes` from the configuration: `data: { roles: [this.configuration.role] }`.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'openOrders', component: OpenOrderListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { roles: [this.configuration.role] } },
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuardService, AppConfigService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  private configuration: AppConfiguration;

  constructor(configService: AppConfigService) {
    this.configuration = configService.configuration;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error from the build process:

> ERROR in app/app-routing.module.ts(27,7): Error during template
> compile of 'AppRoutingModule'   Reference to a local (non-exported)
> symbols are not supported in decorators but 'routes' was referenced
> Consider exporting 'routes'.

How can I overcome this? I suppose this is a naïve issue, but I don't know how to fix this error (remember I'm newbie in angular).

Many thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using angular version:

> Angular CLI: 7.0.7
> Node: 12.21.0
> OS: linux x64
> Angular: 7.0.0

Comment: Simply inject your `AppConfiguration` service into any component and/or  guard where you want to use it.

Comment: data is used to set static data. I agree with the comment above

Comment: That's what I did. We all have come to the same conclusion. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

At last I've followed a different approach. Instead of injecting the configurable value in the data property, I've injected that value in the code where I was using that data value.

Therefore I remove the data property from the route:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'openOrders', component: OpenOrderListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
  ...
];
```

The role data is used in the AuthGuardService. All I have to do is to inject AppConfigService in this class and use the role value from the AppConfiguration instead of the value from the route data:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  configuration: AppConfiguration;
  ...
  constructor(protected router: Router,
              protected keycloakAngular: KeycloakService,
              protected configService: AppConfigService) {
    super(router, keycloakAngular);
    this.configuration = configService.configuration;
  }

  isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
  ...
      const requiredRoles: string[] = [this.configuration.role];
  ...
  }
```

Comment: you don't need `this.configuration = configService.configuration;` and `configuration: AppConfiguration;` instead you can reference the service with the name `this.configService`